# Prevent AdColony advertisements automatically opening the playstore?

Tags: google-play-store, ads, virus

Basically, AdColony is an advertising provider for games, however they use predatory tactics, one of these being an automatic redirect to the playstore the second the ad finishes without any clicking or interaction.

Is there a way I could stop getting these playstore opens?

Comment: You can try a local VPN based ad blocker (VPN client and server are on the same phone) like https://blokada.org